# create react app - ES6 and passport.js

Tags: reactjs, passport.js, adfs, create-react-app

We are using Create React App for building our web application. We would like to integrate our Create React App with Passport.js. I am having a hard time integrating these two considering my app uses classes and passport.js does not follow the same as described below.

https://github.com/chrisprice/adfs-example-integration/blob/master/index.js

Can someone suggest me how to integrate these?

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with classes, but rather ES6 modules, vs NodeJS Common Modules. Luckily, Create React App will use babel underneath to transpile ES6 import statements.

Essentially turn your `var foo = require('bar')` statements into `import foo from 'bar';`

SO:

```
var app = require('express')(),
  cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
  jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
  passport = require('passport'),
  OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth').OAuth2Strategy,
  fs = require('fs');
```

Should be

```
import express from 'express';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import passport from 'passport';
import { OAuth2Strategy } from 'passport-oauth';
import fs from 'fs';

const app = express();
```

This assumes you have those npm modules already installed.

IIRC, Create React App *ONLY* creates a the front-end application. PassportJS is designed to be used in a middle-tier/backend, like an express app. You'll need to create an express app, and mount the passportjs middleware inside the express app.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Do we have any examples on how to create a middleware while using Create React App for front-end applications?

Comment: What are you looking to use passportjs for?

Comment: for ADFS authentication.